Unable to get local issuer certificate error in CentOS 9
When I try to send notification thru OpenProject in CentOS 9. I get an error:

certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate))

When I try directly to test with OpenSSL, I'm able to reach the SMTP server and I don't receive the error.
The OpenSSL command that works :
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -starttls smtp -connect serer:587 -cert /etc/ssl/certs/tls-cert.pem -key /etc/ssl/certs/tls-cert.key -CAfile tls-cert-bundle.pem -servername "ServerName"

Does anyone you any idea why I get this error?
P.S.: I checked the config file on HTTPD for OpenProject and it gives the correct path for the TLS certificate.

Care to provide us screenshots of the exact error you receive? My first guess is your getting an invalid issuer because your creating a self-signed certificate and are not specifically specifying the issuer.

the Certificate is not self signed and actualy it works when i use it directly with Openssl but it fails when i try to use it with Openproject interface, i m guessing sth relates to update system certificate but im not that expert on that field :(

“ i m guessing sth relates to update” - What? I still go back to the certificate it’s lot have the correct issuer for it to throw an error about the issuer. Provide the exact error

ok maybe i wasn't clear :
when i try to connect to the SMTP server with openssl on tls mod it's ok and :
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
SSL handshake has read 4089 bytes and written 491 bytes
Verification: OK
But when i try to connect the smtp server thru the Openproject platform i get error unable to get local issuer

Clarification of your question can be done by editing it

Yes, please edit any clarifications and explanations into your question. A major part of getting good attention and answers on this site is continuing to build and improve your question, and so frequent use of the EDIT button is strongly encouraged. Any time commentors ask clarifying questions, adding the answers to your question is a very good thing.

i was able to fix the issue, i only needed to update the ca-store with the bundle, that's all

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.
